# iOS How to get contact image full screen

Tags: iphone

The AddressBook framework provides ABPersonCopyImageData for getting the contact image for each address book entry. However this API returns original image size which is way too big to display on screen. How does one get a full screen image? Below is the code I am using

```
             NSData *contactImageData = (NSData*)ABPersonCopyImageData(personRef);
             UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:contactImageData];

             self.backgroundImage.image = img; 
             [img release];
             [contactImageData release];
```

where self.backgroundImage is a UIImageView set up in IB with frame rectangle 320x460

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup your `UIImageView` `frame` to be full screen. Then whatever picture you will display in it should be full screen. It will automatically get downsized for you.

Comment: Ah but the contact picture is still the original size and just takes part of the imageview. I need it to be scaled to be in full screen.